How to go through a labyrinth without update erros
I am working on a labyrinth problem for a while now and I have debugged my code a thousand times and cannot find where I am getting it twisted. The prompt is to read a .txt and walk through the labyrinth, adding every decimal number that appears to a total sum, and end the program end it reads '#'. I will attach my solution and the text files i am using as tests, if someone can help me find my logic error. I am pretty sure it is related to either my updates on the lines and columns or my matrix's size.
that was my .txt test file:
6 59
   #                                                       
   5                                                       
   |                                                       
   \-48-3-----6---------------9-5---------2--3--------7-7-\
                                                          |
------------5-------------------0--50---8-------9----4---6/

and there is a larger one
36 80
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
   /-48-3-----6---------------9-5---------2--3--------7-7-\                     
   |                                                      |                     
---|--------5-------------------0--5---8-------9----4---6-|----6---4--68----\   
   |           /0--\                                      |                 |   
   8           0 /-|--------------------4-7-----9------2-6-\                |   
   \---3---6--4|-|-|----09\        /789--0--#---4-00----71||8------------0--/   
               | | |      |        |                      ||                    
               | 5 |      |        |                      |4                    
     /6--11-9--2-----2-------1-7--1----\                  85                    
     5         | 3 |      |        |   |                  5|                    
     |         | | |      4        |   #                  ||                    
     |         | 4 |      |        |                      1|                    
     |         | | |      2        |                      ||                    
     |         3 0 |      |        9                      ||                    
     |         | | |      |        8  /2----7-------------8|2--2----0-----3\    
     |         | | 1      |        1  |                   ||               |    
     3         | | |      |        |  |                   |8               0    
     \-7--4------91/      |        \--|----3-------6----73/|               7    
               \-----3------634-----90---965-8------------6/               |    
                 |        7           |                                    |    
                 |        \---5----8--/                                    |    
                 |                                                         |    
                 \-------------4---9-2-5--1-37-15---2--2--6----9---1-25----/    

that was my solution, the variables are in portuguese because i'm brazilian:
nome = 'x1.txt'
doc = []

with open(nome, 'r') as file:
    for l in file:
        linha = list(l.strip())
        doc.append(linha)

doc = [[element for element in row if element != '\n'] for row in doc]
linhas = ''
colunas = ''
achou = False


for carac in doc[0]:
    if carac == ' ':
        achou= True
    elif not achou:
        linhas += carac
    else:
        colunas += carac

linhas = int(linhas)
colunas = int(colunas)
# doc.remove(doc[0])
print(linhas, colunas)
print(doc)

somaTotal = 0
num = 0

def esq_dir(linhaA, colunaA):
    global num
    global somaTotal
    num = '0'
    c = colunaA
    for i in range(c, colunas):
        carac = doc[linhaA][i]
        print(carac)
        print(linhaA, colunaA)
        if carac == '#':
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
            break
        if carac == '-' or carac == '|':
            colunaA += 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
        if carac == '/':
            # colunaA += 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            linhaA -= 1
            subindo(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        if carac == '\\':
            # colunaA += 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            linhaA += 1
            descendo(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        elif carac.isdigit():
            num += carac
            colunaA += 1

def dir_esq(linhaA, colunaA):
    global somaTotal
    global num
    num = '0'
    c = colunaA
    for i in range(c -1,-1, -1):
        carac = doc[linhaA][i]
        print(carac)
        print(linhaA, colunaA)
        if carac == '#':
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
            break
        if carac == '-' or carac == '|':
            colunaA -= 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
        if carac == '\\':
            linhaA += 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            subindo(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        if carac == '/':
            linhaA -= 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            descendo(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        elif carac.isdigit():
            num += carac
            colunaA -= 1

def descendo(linhaA, colunaA):
    global somaTotal
    num = '0'
    l = linhaA
    for i in range(l, linhas):
        carac = doc[i][colunaA]
        print(carac)
        if carac == '#':
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
            break
        if carac == '-' or carac == '|':
            linhaA += 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
        if carac == '/':
            colunaA -= 1
            dir_esq(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        if carac == '\\':
            colunaA += 1
            esq_dir(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        elif carac.isdigit():
            num += carac
            linhaA += 1

def subindo(linhaA, colunaA):
    global somaTotal
    num = '0' # troquei de '' para 0 para evitar syntax errors
    l = linhaA
    for i in range(l - 1,-1, -1): # alterei para -1 o 'stop' pois não estava lendo a condição de parada (#), portanto não somava o 4
        carac = doc[i][colunaA]
        print(carac)
        print(linhaA, colunaA)
        if carac == '#':
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
            break
        if carac == '-' or carac == '|':
            linhaA -=1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            num = '0'
        if carac == '/':
            colunaA += 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            esq_dir(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        if carac == '\\':
            linhaA -= 1
            somaTotal += int(num)
            dir_esq(linhaA, colunaA)
            break
        elif carac.isdigit():
            num += carac 
            linhaA -= 1


linhaAtual = 0
colunaAtual = 0

for i, linha in enumerate(doc):
    if linha and linha[0] == '-':
        linhaAtual = i
        break

# print(doc)
# print(linhaAtual)

esq_dir(linhaAtual, colunaAtual)
print(somaTotal)type here


Where is code explanation (comments)? Where is desired output? What language it is?

"i'm brazilian:" Most of us are not that lucky. I could try and read your program, but it would be a bit of a struggle. Please consider using English for identifiers and comments in your future programs. Chances are, you will need to show it to someone who doesn't speak your language.

"adding every decimal number that appears to a total sum" It isn't clear what you need to do if you see say two characters 15, add the number 15 or add 1 and then add 5? In either case, num += carac doesn't seem to be correct.

Is this Python? Then you should add [tag:python] tag.

fyi you can also move your question to [pt.so].  But whether keeping it here or moving to the Portuguese-specific site: you still need to provide all relevant details, not just code. Provide specific inputs, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc (basically, a [mcve]).

Are you trying to create a labyrinth or read a labyrinth from a text file? For input, the format is not great because there are ambiguous situations; eg crossing with a number, is it 1 and then 2 or 12, can't put numbers more then 9 on vertical, etc.

The main problem is that you strip the input lines. This removes all leading spaces from each line and so destroys the consistency of the labyrinth. For instance, the first example will look like this:
#                                                       
5                                                       
|                                                       
\-48-3-----6---------------9-5---------2--3--------7-7-\
|
------------5-------------------0--50---8-------9----4---6/

...and the / and \ corners are disconnected.
These statements should replace your file processing part:
with open(nome, 'r') as file:
    doc = [line for line in file.read().splitlines()[1:] if line]
linhas = len(doc)
colunas = len(doc[0])

I didn't look for other problems in your code, but I would advise you to:

Use functions, with local variables that are only used there
Avoid global variables
Avoid code repetition. The code you have for the 4 directions is very similar and you should be able to have this only once, with some variables that take care of going in the right direction.

Here's how it could be eventually:
def load_maze(nome):
    with open(nome, 'r') as file:
        return [line for line in file.read().splitlines()[1:] if line]

def find_start(maze):
    return next(i for i, line in enumerate(maze) if line[0] == '-')

def walk(maze, row, col, dir):
    num = "0"
    total = 0
    while True:
        ch = maze[row][col]
        if ch.isdigit():
            num += ch
        else:
            total += int(num)
            num = "0"
            if ch == "/":
                dir ^= 1  # toggle between east-south or west-north
            elif ch == "\\":
                dir ^= 3  # toggle between east-north or west-south
            elif ch == "#":
                return total
        row += (dir == 1) - (dir == 3)  # south:1  north:-1
        col += (dir == 0) - (dir == 2)  # east: 1  west: -1
    
maze = load_maze('x1.txt')
row = find_start(maze)
total = walk(maze, row, 0, 0)
print(total)

